# Is selector inside a scss mixin valid?

Tags: html, css, sass

CSS syntax in general is

```
selector {
 declarations ...
}
```

I have mostly seen mixin taking care of `declaration` part

example

```
@mixin border-radius($rad) {
 border-radius: $rad;
}

// and used like 

some-selector {
 @include border-radius(5px)
}
```

but can a mixin return a complete selector itself

```
@mixin button {
  .button {
    color: red
  }
}

// now if I have button nested in any of my dom element I can say

selector-for-dom-element {
  @include button;
}
```

is the second case valid syntax?

I have seen that it works but not sure if its documented and should I use it in production.

as an answer to this, I am only looking to confirm that its valid syntax and any reference to such a claim.

Or I am doing it the wrong way, any other way to do it... except using `extend`?

Comment: No references but if it compiles, then yes it is valid SCSS. However, I can't see any case in which this practice could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly include selectors within a mixin, and there *are* examples of this in the Sass documentation. The very first code example on the [@mixin and @include](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) page is actually quite similar to your example in that a mixin is called from a type selector, which results in a descendant selector. Here's the relevant part of that example:

```
@mixin horizontal-list {
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: {
      left: -2px;
      right: 2em;
    }
  }
}

nav ul {
  @include horizontal-list;
}
```

That compiles to:

```
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -2px;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

Your example uses a class selector, but the principle is the same. Here's the compiled CSS:

```
selector-for-dom-element .button {
  color: red;
}
```